# Soundcloud API return only mp3 formats?

Tags: html, audio, soundcloud, ogg

I get track info from soundcloud, and use stream_url property for initialising html5 audio, but it works only in chrome, safari, and IE. How I can get .ogg track for opera and firefox, if it possible?

Answer (score 4):

128 kbp/s mp3 is currently the only audio format available for streams on SoundCloud.

We've made some good experience with [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) as it provides a Flash fallback for browsers that don't support mp3 natively.

Comment: In [html5-widget (2012/01/26)](http://blog.soundcloud.com/2012/01/26/html5-widget/#comment-425520036) Matas Petrikas said that: _We hope we can add native HTML5 ogg streams in the upcoming months_. When will this happen? Is there a specific date?

Comment: @TimPietrusky no, there's no specific date right now. We're following the developments very closely [and pushing](http://areweplayingyet.org/) for better standards across all browsers.

Comment: @nickf Thanks. I will look into [areweplayingyet](http://areweplayingyet.org) and hope to contribute something useful.

Comment: @nickf so after 3 years... will ogg streams be available on SoundCloud at some point? Are there any plans?

Comment: @TimPietrusky no plans that I know of. In the meantime, browser support of mp3 playback has improved a lot. Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE9+ and even Firefox all support it now. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) There doesn't seem to be much need for duplicating the 200 million or so audio files *(judging by the autoincrement track ids)*

Answer (score 1):

Canvas.fm used Node.js to handle SoundCloud's incoming MP3 stream, and then piped this into ffmpeg, giving an OGG formatted audio stream could then be piped into an HTTP response.

Using Node.js makes this kind of stream handling incredibly simple and efficient.

REFS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs

http://canvas.fm (new details in comments below)

Hope that helps

Comment: There are more details about the canvas.fm project here http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2011/10/26/experiments-with-the-html5-audio-data-api and the code is available here https://github.com/olivernn/canvas.fm

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [node-lame](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame) to decode the mp3 stream to raw PCM data, then encode that stream into an ogg stream using [node-ogg](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-ogg) and then serve that to the clients. If you're not sure how to proceed with that I suggest reading this blog post from yours truly: http://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/streaming-audio-on-the-web-with-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

Opera and Firefox have support for MP3 HTML5 Audio now.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats